# Soma com inner join Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, inner

Pessoal preciso de um auxilio, necessito criar um relatório que mostre a quantidade total de cada produto em estoque, porém não consigo fazer aparecer o nome dos produtos, somente o código do produto e a soma da quantidade dos produtos que tenho. Segue abaixo o código que fiz:

```
SELECT 
    c.COD_PRODUTO,
    SUM(b.QTD_SALDO) AS SALDO 
FROM ESTOQUE_1 b
INNER JOIN ESTOQUE_2 c ON b.COD_PRODUTO = c.COD_PRODUTO
WHERE COD_PRODUTO IN ('6306','6308','6307','6234')
GROUP BY COD_PRODUTO;
```

Nesse código tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
SKU                            SALDO
------------------------- ----------
51231535                         210 
68000512                          24 
50388958                        1000 
50387203                        6000
```

Eu preciso que apareça o nome do item, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
NOME  SKU                            SALDO
----- ------------------------- ----------
      51231535                         210 
      68000512                          24 
      50388958                        1000 
      50387203                        6000
```

A tabela que contém o nome do produto é a ESTOQUE_2

A estrutura da tabela é:

```
ESTOQUE_1
COD_PRODUTO | QTD_SALDO

ESTOQUE_2
COD_PRODUTO | NOME_PRODUTO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode colocar C.NOME_PRODUTO na select e no Group by. Assim o resultado vai retornar o agrupamento desejado

```
SELECT
    C.NOME_PRODUTO,
    c.COD_PRODUTO,
    SUM(b.QTD_SALDO) AS SALDO 
FROM ESTOQUE_1 b 
INNER JOIN ESTOQUE_2 c 
   ON b.COD_PRODUTO = c.COD_PRODUTO 
WHERE COD_PRODUTO IN ('6306','6308','6307','6234') 
GROUP BY COD_PRODUTO, C.NOME_PRODUTO;
```

Answer (score 0):

basta você adicionar a coluna da tabela c no Select e no Group by

```
SELECT 
    c.NOME_PRODUTO,
    c.COD_PRODUTO,
    SUM(b.QTD_SALDO) AS SALDO 
FROM ESTOQUE_1 b
INNER JOIN ESTOQUE_2 c ON b.COD_PRODUTO = c.COD_PRODUTO
WHERE COD_PRODUTO IN ('6306','6308','6307','6234')
GROUP BY c.COD_PRODUTO,c.NOME_PRODUTO;
```

Comment: Obrigado Rovann, deu certo aqui!!!

Comment: @Ikki_Nogueira não se esqueça de marcar como resposta. Obrigado e bem vindo a comunidade.